# Laravel 9 Route problem return 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to render a view but I always get notfoud 404 I don't know how to solve this question anymore if anyone can help me I would be grateful.
any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.
Everyone have a great Monday.

[image]

CommunityPostController -> code ->

```
public function creategif(Community $community)
{
    return view('posts.creategif', compact('community'));
}
```

---

Web Routes

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('u/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'user'])->name('user.view');

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);


Route::group(['middleware' =>['auth', 'verified']], function (){

    Route::resource('communities', \App\Http\Controllers\CommunityController::class);
    Route::resource('communities.posts', \App\Http\Controllers\CommunityPostController::class);
    Route::resource('posts.comments', \App\Http\Controllers\PostCommentController::class);
    Route::get('communities/{community}/posts/creategif', [\App\Http\Controllers\CommunityPostController::class, 'creategif']);


    Route::get('posts/{post_id}/vote/{vote}', [\App\Http\Controllers\CommunityPostController::class, 'vote'])->name('post.vote');
});
```

---

Views Files Structure

[image]

Comment: cleared the routes cache? made sure the community actually exists? authed and email verified user?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. Yes cleared routes cache.  im have create.blade.php file works fine. yes community exists. but problem is in creategif.blade.php no render :(

Comment: put this  Route::get('communities/{community}/posts/creategif', [\App\Http\Controllers\CommunityPostController::class, 'creategif']); above your communities resource.  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers  . Note: Route:resource()  will write multiple endpoints /communities/XXX/  communities/xxx/xxx  etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a conflict base on your route order and the image you've posted. As you can see you have resource for your route which in this case this conflict might happen base on route order, and your laravel is actually trying to get a `post` instead of loading `creategif` route.

Which in this case every time you try to get access to `creategif` route, your application is actually trying to load a post base on `'communities.posts'` route.

[image]

So base on this conflict in your route order, this is working fine and create or any other routes related to `'communities.posts'` should work fine, but in other-hand `creategif` in `URL` might recognized as a route related to `'communities.posts'` resource.

Move your route to top, or in this case just above `'communities.posts'` route, don't forget to clear route cache.

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>['auth', 'verified']], function (){

    Route::get('communities/{community}/posts/creategif', [\App\Http\Controllers\CommunityPostController::class, 'creategif']);
    Route::resource('communities', \App\Http\Controllers\CommunityController::class);
    Route::resource('communities.posts', \App\Http\Controllers\CommunityPostController::class);
    Route::resource('posts.comments', \App\Http\Controllers\PostCommentController::class);


    Route::get('posts/{post_id}/vote/{vote}', [\App\Http\Controllers\CommunityPostController::class, 'vote'])->name('post.vote');
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. But same problem :(

Comment: try to comment `'communities.posts'` route, and see if it's working or it's not.

Comment: @Davi try to clear, route cache, then try again. if it didn't worked, try to comment `'communities.posts'` and clear route cache, to find out. following approach in answer should fix your problem, but there might be a caching problem too, and if you didn't cleared your cache, you should do it before you try again.

Comment: Now the view has been rendered. but no function noworks

Comment: @Davi well you've got your answer, but in case you have more errors, maybe update your question or create with more details, because I don't know what is causing errors base on no details.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I believe that the following problems I'll be trying to solve, just rendering it makes me happy. Thanks again. :D

Comment: @Davi good luck, I feel like the conflict might be related to top, but I don't know what is happening in your application, since details are not enough.

Comment: This solved for me. Moving Route::get('route..') above Route::resource('route..') did the thing.